# list all students who have not taken midterm for 1 or more subjects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables likes `Student`,`Subject`,and `Midterm` tables.

`Student` table contains

```
studid Firstname lastname Class

1      A       R        12A
2      B       S        12A
3      C       T        12A
4      D       U        12A
5      E       V        12B
```

`SUBJECT` table contains

```
subid subname
  1     maths
  2     science
  3     english
```

`MIDTERM` table contains

```
studid subid marks examdate
1        1    100  2014-09-24
1        2     92  2014-09-25
1        2     92  2014-09-26
2        1     74  2014-09-24
2        2     78  2014-09-26
2        3     73  2014-09-26
3        1     90  2014-09-24
3        2     84  2014-09-25
3        2     92  2014-09-25
5        1     87  2014-09-24
4        2     79  2014-09-24
4        3     90  2014-09-26
```

The result must be:

```
Firstname LastName Subname
```

Comment: The result must be
Firstname LastName Subname

Comment: Please show us your effort. If you haven't tried or not sure how to do it. Google `joins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the below comment and Assuming all Students must take all midterms

```
select Firstname , lastname , subname
from (
select studid , FirstName, lastname , subID , subname
from student , Subject) d
left outer join midterm m on d.studid = m.studID and d.subid = m.subid
where m.examdate is null
```

could probably write it without the catesian join but it should suffice

Comment: i want to list all students who have not taken midterm for 1 or more subjects...the result must be Firstname,Lastname,subname

Answer (score 0):

As I guess, the one who didn't pass a midterm is "the one who has less than 50 points".
If not, you can fix it in the last line.

You can use `INNER JOIN` SQL keyword to make a query to several logically interconnected tables definining a matching condition.

Simply said, first you need to understand how you will extract data logically.
For example, in your case you need to select from `MIDTERM` table as it stores both student id and subject id.

In words, it sounds like:
 1. Take all results of failed midterms (midterms with marks < 50). Each row contains `studid` (who failed an exam) and `subid` (which exam he failed);
 2. From table `Student` take FirstName and LastName of student who failed it;
 3. From table `Subject` take Subname of subject which has been failed;
 4. Return these three values.

In code, it looks like:

```
SELECT s.Firstname, s.Lastname, subj.subname FROM `MIDTERM`
FROM `MIDTERM` as m
INNER JOIN `Student` as s ON s.stuid = m.studid
INNER JOIN `SUBJECT` as subj ON subj.subid = m.subid
WHERE `marks` < 50
```

Comment: with CTE(studid,examdate,Row_num)as (
  select studid,examdate,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by studid order by studid) Row_num
      from [StudentDetails].dbo.[MidTermTable] group by studid,examdate having COUNT(subid)>1 )
     select t.studid,s3.SubID,t.examdate,t.Row_num from CTE T
      join [StudentDetails].dbo.MidTermTable s1 on t.studid=s1.StudID 
      and t.examdate=s1.ExamDate
      join [StudentDetails].dbo.StudentTable s2 on s1.StudID=s2.StudID
      join [StudentDetails].dbo.SubjectTable s3 on s1.SubID=s3.SubID

Comment: In the above query how do i make that query simple.Also Row number must be included.can anyone please help me